# Pascal ERROR Range check error help me find my mistakes

Tags: pascal

I was trying to make a cashier program right, and I think I did everything right but I faced an error that I dont know how to fix.

```
uses
  crt;

var
  harga, jumlah, total, final: integer;
  nama, kode: string;
  totalCost: integer = 0;  // initialize total cost to zero
  y : integer = 3;

begin
  clrscr;
  repeat
    gotoxy(50, 1); write('TOKO AMANAH MURAH');
    gotoxy(50, 3); write('Nama Item        | Jumlah Barang | Total');
    gotoxy(1,4);write('Kode barang   : ');readln(kode);
    gotoxy(1,5);write('Jumlah barang : ');readln(jumlah);
    if kode = 'susu' then
    begin
      nama := 'SUSU KOTAK';
      harga := 2000;
    end
    else 
    if kode = 'kopi' then
    begin
      nama := 'Kopi Cair' ;
      harga := 3000;
    end
    else
    begin
      nama:= 'Invalid';
      harga := 0;
    end;

    total := harga * jumlah;
    totalCost := totalCost + total;
    y := y + 1;
    // Display the item list and total cost on the right side of the screen
    gotoxy(50, y); write(nama , ' | ' , jumlah , ' | Rp' , total);
    gotoxy(50, 8); write('Total: Rp', totalCost);
  until kode = '';
end.
```

I tried removing, adding changing how the code runs but nothing works. I'm pretty new to pascal and did everything I could , thank you.

Comment: You did not specify which statement gives the range error. My guess would be `total := harga*jumlah`. If integers are 16 bits, it does not take large values to overflow the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Function gotoxy() expects two byte parameters (which can have values from 0 to 255) and you are providing an integer (variable 'y').
The value of 'y' keeps incrementing, and when it reaches the value of 256 you get the range error.
You should somehow control/avoid the variable 'y' from getting beyond 255.